# how to start SP designer workflow using Remote Event Reciever after item deleted from list?

Tags: designer-workflow, remote-event-receiver

I wan to send email after item got deleted from list for that I used delete item action in designer workflow but that doesn't got triggered and am not able to do this using Remote Event Reciever.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but it should work

SPWorkflowManager wfManager = properties.ListItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.WorkflowManager;

SPWorkflowAssociation workflowAssociation = properties.List.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName("workflownamehere", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

wfManager.StartWorkflow(properties.ListItem, wfAssociation, wfAssociation.AssociationData);